# clicking word which changes to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want to achieve is to be able to click text on screen and then the text I clicked changes to another word.

For example :

if I click 'view as list' I want it to change to 'Thumbnails'

Here is my attempt below:

html code:

```
<div class="page-intro">
    <h2>Artists</h2>
    <h2 class="thumb-to-list">View As List</h2>
</div>
```

css code:

```
.page-intro {
  background: orange;
}

.page-intro h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
  display: inline-block;
}

.thumb-to-list {
  float: right;
}
```

Here is my attempt at code but it's not working:

```
$('.thumb-to-list').toggle(function() {
    $('.thumb-to-list').text('View As Thumbnails');
}, function() {
    $('.thumb-to-list').text('View As List');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use `on()` function, because Your DOM doesn't changes by changing it's values/text. You should just use [click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/) function.

```
$('.thumb-to-list').click(function() {
    $(this).text('View As Thumbnails');
}
```

Comment: I know what is the difference between those function. There is no need to use .on() in here.

Comment: .click is old and will be deprecated eventually.  People stopped using that ages ago.  Go learn some jquery

Comment: Source about that info?

Comment: @NotoriousPet0 Could be wrong but I'm pretty sure based on the official docs that `.click()` uses `.on()` internally. Here's a snippet from the docs: _"This method is a shortcut for .on( "click", handler ) in the first two variations, and .trigger( "click" ) in the third."_ **Source**: [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) That being said I tend to use `.on()` simply because I like consistency between the attaching of all my event handlers. As far as I can see though based on the docs, it's perfectly acceptable either way.

Comment: OK, I didn't realize they had changed it.  They must have done that recently.  They used to be different.  Good to know.  You learn something new every day.

Answer (score 2):

You can use directly the `click` event :

```
$(".thumb-to-list").click(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == "View As Thumbnails")
       $(this).text("View As List")
    else
       $(this).text("View As Thumbnails");
});
```

Comment: yeah i saw that the other guy posted that.  gave you an upvote since i was wrong

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind your mouse click to an event

```js
$('.thumb-to-list').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).text() == "View As List") {
    $(this).html('View As Thumbnails');
  } else {
    $(this).html('View As List');
  }
});
```

```css
.page-intro {
  background: orange;
}
.page-intro h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
  display: inline-block;
}
.thumb-to-list {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-intro">
  <h2>Artists</h2>
  <h2 class="thumb-to-list">View As List</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use `.click()`, use `.on()` instead. Also, `.html()` is better than `.text()`.